# Deleted my only Launcher and APK - Black Screen. Please help!

Tags: rom-flashing, rom, apk, lenovo, flashtool

I have a Lenovo A806. The device was rooted and I downloaded a root uninstaller from the PlayStore to uninstall some apps that I couldn't otherwise.

In the process, among other apps, I deleted the only launcher I had on the phone (Lenovo Launcher) and I might have deleted the APK (not sure about the APK). The result was a black screen without any apps.

When turn on the phone I can see the home screen (same one you see before you unlock keyboard) and I also have some of the functionalities (eg messages, can make calls etc). However, if I open one of these functionalities and I click on the "back" button, the screen goes completely black and the phone goes unresponsive.

I tried to,

- reset factory settings by holding the Volume Up + Down + On/Off button which opened the "Lenovo Recovery" screen and I choosing the "wipe user data (both fuse format and fuse wipe data).
- install update package option and I rebooted the phone. Nothing of those worked.

Could anyone direct me towards the right way?

Comment: Copy the zip file to phone/sdcard, get into "Lenovo recovery" and install the zip.Try Zipped [Google now](http://d-h.st/xQ4) or any other launcher(`.zip`) .

Answer (score 0):

1. Open play store in your pc
2. Install any launcher app like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher&hl=en)
3. When installed you will get a prompt in notification
4. Clicking it will take you to play store
5. Click open which will give a launcher

Answer (score 0):

If you can go to Settings of your phone (which I think you can - when in messaging or phone UI you should still be able to use the notification shade), turn on USB Debugging from there, connect the phone to your PC (assuming proper drivers have been installed), and sideload a launcher onto the phone with "adb install".

As for the sideloaded launcher, get whatever you like from APKPure, APKMirror or other trusted APK sites.